# transform into if/else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

somehow this doesn't work:

```
if(direction != 'leftnav') direction = 'leftnav'; 
if(direction == 'leftnav') direction = 'rightie';
```

this always comes out as "rightie"

I tend to believe this is because they kind of overwrite. Can this be done with an if else statement?
thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`!==` and `===` are [strict equality checks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

You probably just want `!=`, like the following:

```
if (direction != 'leftnav') {
  direction = 'leftnav';
}
else {
  direction = 'rightie';
}
```

Or better yet for these simple assignments, using a [ternary operator](http://www.gsdesign.ro/blog/how-to-use-ternary-operator-in-javascript/):

```
direction = direction == 'leftnav' ? 'rightie' : 'leftnav';
```

Comment: the !== wasnt the problem but the if else fixed it! thanks a lot :)

Comment: That's because you're updated code set's `direction` twice if you pass the first `if`. That is to say if `direction = 5`, the first `if` sets `direction = 'leftnav'`. Then you'll pass the second `if`, setting it to `rightie`. For situations like this you should really use `if/else` blocks.

Comment: yup seen that :) I guessed that already but i just didn't know how to turn it into an else statement :).

Answer (score 2):

Of course they overwrite, look at what you're doing there:

```
if(direction !== 'leftnav') direction = 'leftnav';
if(direction == 'leftnav') direction = 'rightie';
```

The first statement sets `direction` to 'leftnav' if it is anything else. So by the time you get to the second statement, `direction` will always be 'leftnav'. Did you mean to say `else if` rather than just `if` for the second?

Comment: And you could just use `else` instead of `else if` for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the logic you are asking for:

If it is not leftnav, then make it leftnav.
[Next statement -- after it has already been reassigned]
If it is leftnav, make it rightie.

You're looking for

```
if(direction !== 'leftnav') direction = 'leftnav';
else if(direction == 'leftnav') direction = 'rightie'; // can just be "else"
```